# Login Form Redirecting to Login Page?

Tags: magento-1.9.2

I have added the following code to the page for https://cashino.kellyseye.com/

```
<div class="top-content-text cf m-all t-1of2 d-1of2 first">
<h3>Store Login</h3>
<div class="block block-login"><form 
action="https://cashino.kellyseye.com/customer/account/loginPost/" 
method="post">
<div class="block-content"><input id="mini-login" class="input-text" 
spellcheck="false" type="email" placeholder="Email:" name="login[username]" 
/> <input id="mini-password" class="input-text" type="password" 
placeholder="Password:" name="login[password]" /> <input type="hidden" 
value="&lt;?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')-&gt;getFormKey() ? 
&gt;" name="form_key" />
<div class="actions"><button class="button" type="submit"> <span> 
<span>Login</span> </span> </button></div>
</div>
</form></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, when I enter my credentials and click "Login", I am redirected to the login page, where I have to add my credentials once again.

On other pages for example https://beaconbingo.kellyseye.com/ I have no problem logging in from the form on the homepage.

Why is this?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I have checked and its working fine. Check it in private browser it should work.

Comment: I have tried incognito and I have cleared my cache. It doesn't allow the user to log in by the form on the homepage. It redirects them to the login page even though they've entered their email and password.

Comment: I have created an account there with test@test.com email id and it works fine. Can you try with different email id or create new account then try>?